# AMP validation error: "The mandatory text inside tag 'head > style[amp-boilerplate]' is missing or incorrect."

Tags: amp-html

I copied and pasted the mandated code from [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-boilerplate.md).
This is from the page source:

```
  <style amp-boilerplate>
        body {
            -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;
            -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;
            -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;
            animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
            from {
                visibility: hidden
            }

            to {
                visibility: visible
            }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
            from {
                visibility: hidden
            }

            to {
                visibility: visible
            }
        }

        @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
            from {
                visibility: hidden
            }

            to {
                visibility: visible
            }
        }

        @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
            from {
                visibility: hidden
            }

            to {
                visibility: visible
            }
        }

        @keyframes -amp-start {
            from {
                visibility: hidden
            }

            to {
                visibility: visible
            }
        }
    </style>
    <noscript>
        <style amp-boilerplate>
            body {
                -webkit-animation: none;
                -moz-animation: none;
                -ms-animation: none;
                animation: none
            }
        </style>
    </noscript>
```

I am still getting the following validation error:

> The mandatory text inside tag 'head > style[amp-boilerplate]' is
> missing or incorrect. (see
> https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-boilerplate.md)

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't worked a lot with AMP, is this the only `style` tag you have inside the `head` tag?

Comment: No, there are other styles.  I thought styles were allowed.  If not, the validation should complain about it.

Comment: Can you post a gist of your other `style` tags? I think they are missing the `amp-custom` attribute

Comment: I am terribly sorry but I have realized that I copied a wrong error message.  I have corrected it.  Thank you for trying to lend a hand here.  My apology again.

Comment: Not at all. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMP expects the boilerplate to remain minified. I just pasted your boilerplate code into an AMP Playground document and got the exact same error you are getting.

Just to confirm it is the minifying, I minified your boilerplate from your post and it worked.

```
<style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
```

Edit:

I did a little more playing around. You can add returns before and after the opening and closing tags. Adding any returns or spaces to the CSS itself appears to be prohibited.

```css
<style amp-boilerplate> 
    body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}
 </style>
 <noscript>
   <style amp-boilerplate>
     body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}
   </style>
 </noscript>
```

[Here is a link](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/spec/amp-boilerplate) explaining the AMP Boilerplate code and allowed changes. Basically you can only add white space immediately after the tags, and you can add more white space where it already exists.

> AMP HTML documents must contain the following boilerplate in their head tag. Validation is currently done with regular expressions, so it's important to keep mutations as minimal as possible. Currently, allowed mutations are: (1) inserting arbitrary whitespace immediately after the style tag opens, and immediately before it closes; (2) replacing any space in the snippet below with arbitrary whitespace.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I am down to only one validation error for my first AMP page now.

Comment: No problem! If you get stuck on your last error I am happy to help.

Comment: I really appreciate your great help.  Here is the last error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51758230/amp-validation-error-the-mandatory-attribute-amp-custom-is-missing-in-tag-st