# AMP validation error "The mandatory attribute 'amp-custom' is missing in tag 'style amp-custom'..."

Tags: amp-html

A web page has the following AMP validation error:

> The mandatory attribute 'amp-custom' is missing in tag 'style
>   amp-custom'. (see
>   https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/author-develop/responsive/style_pages)

I searched the page source, and could not find "amp-custom".  In other words, the page does not have tag 'style amp-custom'.

Could anyone offer a hint on a possible cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on my phone so bear with me here... amp-custom is where you include your custom CSS. It goes before the amp-boilerplate in the head so as to not overwrite anything the boilerplate is doing. Check out the page about adding custom CSS on the AMP project page: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/style_pages

All CSS must be inline, you cannot use a link tag to include your CSS. You can either hardcode the CSS inline or you can include it via PHP or the method shown on the page linked above. There is a file size limit to the amount of CSS allowed as well.

Comment: Hallelujah! My first validated AMP page is born with your great help.  Thanks a lot! If I were to write the validation error, I would have it like "Your inline style is missing the mandatory attribute 'amp-custom'".

Comment: Awesome! If you have suggestions for AMP you can always visit the amp-html GitHub and make a post for your suggestion. https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues

Comment: I actually made one this morning though it is related to another issue: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/17382

Answer (score -1):

AMP CSS style is put in head enclosed within

```
<style amp-custom>
    <!--Your CSS-->
</style>
```

Here you seem to have put it as

```
<style>
     <!--Your CSS-->
</style>
```

So, the error says amp-custom attribute is missing.
Just add amp-custom within opening style tag